# Every 51 or 52 records - write failed: EBADF

Tags: android

I have an Android App that reads records from 1 file and writes them to another file.

On my Galaxy S4, it **works fine**. On my Galaxy Tablet 10.1 and older Nexus phone, it fails when writing after a few thousand records, and then go into a pattern of **failing** every 51 or 52 records. The error message I get is `write failed: EBADF (Bad file number)`.

I am lost as to why this always works on 1 device but fails consistently on my tablet and old Nexus phone.

It strange (to me) that once I hit the first failure on the write statement, it goes into a pattern of writing the next 51 or 52 records before having the EBADF error again. Any ideas on what is causing the problem?

```
int saveSegmentCounter=0;
while (ACCTime<=ACCTimeArray[ACCendPointer] && eofACC==false) {
    //Log.d(tag, "Map3-1 doTrimFiles - lineACC="+lineACC);
    //write the new ACC record
    try {
        fACCWriter.write(lineACC+"\n"); //why does this fail sometimes???
        saveSegmentCounter++;
        //Log.d(tag, "Map3 doTrimFiles Try when writing ACC number "+saveSegmentCounter);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(tag, "Map3 doTrimFiles Catch when writing ACC number "+saveSegmentCounter); //Fails every 54 or 53 records???
        Log.d(tag, "Map3 e.getmessage: "+ e.getMessage()); //Fails every 54 or 53 records???
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ReadACCFile(null); //read the next acc record
}
```

The stacktrace produces:

> 01-11 21:52:21.306: D/Events(6449): Map3 doTrimFiles Catch when
>   writing ACC number 9348    01-11 21:52:21.306: D/Events(6449): Map3
>   e.getmessage: write failed: EBADF (Bad file number)    01-11
>   21:52:21.306: W/System.err(6449): java.io.IOException: write failed:
>   EBADF (Bad file number)    01-11 21:52:21.306: W/System.err(6449): at
>   libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:455) 01-11 21:52:21.306:
>   W/System.err(6449): at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:187) 01-11
>   21:52:21.306: W/System.err(6449): at
>   java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBytes(OutputStreamWriter.java:167)
>   01-11 21:52:21.306: W/System.err(6449): at
>   java.io.OutputStreamWriter.convert(OutputStreamWriter.java:181) 01-11
>   21:52:21.306: W/System.err(6449): at
>   java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:324) 01-11
>   21:52:21.306: W/System.err(6449): at
>   java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:141) 01-11 21:52:21.306:
>   W/System.err(6449): at
>   com.grimmersoftware.roadbump1.Map3$1.onClick(Map3.java:852) 01-11
>   21:52:21.306: W/System.err(6449): at
>   com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
>   01-11 21:52:21.306: W/System.err(6449): at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 01-11
>   21:52:21.306: W/System.err(6449): at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 01-11 21:52:21.306:
>   W/System.err(6449): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476) 01-11
>   21:52:21.306: W/System.err(6449): at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 01-11
>   21:52:21.306: W/System.err(6449): at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 01-11 21:52:21.306:
>   W/System.err(6449): at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
>   01-11 21:52:21.306: W/System.err(6449): at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 01-11
>   21:52:21.306: W/System.err(6449): at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 01-11 21:52:21.311:
>   W/System.err(6449): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: write
>   failed: EBADF (Bad file number)    01-11 21:52:21.311:
>   W/System.err(6449): at libcore.io.Posix.writeBytes(Native Method)
>   01-11 21:52:21.311: W/System.err(6449): at
>   libcore.io.Posix.write(Posix.java:202) 01-11 21:52:21.311:
>   W/System.err(6449): at
>   libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.write(BlockGuardOs.java:197) 01-11
>   21:52:21.311: W/System.err(6449): at
>   libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:450) 01-11 21:52:21.311:
>   W/System.err(6449): ... 15 more